# How to group pandas DataFrame if some values are range of integers, while others are pure integer?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group a df by a column `col_2`, which contains mostly `integers`, but some cells contain a **range of integers**. In my real life example, each unique integer represents a specific serial number of an assembled part. Each row in the dataframe represents a single part, which is allocated to the assembled part by `col_2`. Some parts can only be allocated to the assembled part with a given uncertainty (range). 
The expected output would be **one** single group **for each** referenced integer (assembled part S/N). For example, the entry col_1 = c should be allocated to both groups where col_2 = 1 and col_2 = 2.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame( {'col_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
                    'col_2': [1, 2, range(1,3), 3,range(2,5),5]})

  col_1      col_2
0     a          1
1     b          2
2     c     (1, 2)
3     d          3
4     e  (2, 3, 4)
5     f          5

print(df.groupby(['col_2']).groups)
```

The code above gives an error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'int'

Comment: What would be the expected output there? `a` in one group, `b, c, d, e` in another (and what would it considered as? Would it be `2, range(1, 3), 3, or range(2, 5)`?) and `f` in another maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
s = df.col_2.apply(pd.Series).set_index(df.col_1).stack().astype(int)
s.reset_index().groupby(0).col_1.apply(list)
```

The first step gives you:

```
col_1   
a      0    1
b      0    2
c      0    1
       1    2
d      0    3
e      0    2
       1    3
       2    4
f      0    5
```

And the final result is:

```
1       [a, c]
2    [b, c, e]
3       [d, e]
4          [e]
5          [f]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

````
df = pd.DataFrame( {'col_1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
                    'col_2': [1, 2, range(1,3), 3,range(2,5),5]})

  col_1      col_2
0     a          1
1     b          2
2     c     (1, 2)
3     d          3
4     e  (2, 3, 4)
5     f          5
df['col_2'] = df.col_2.map(lambda x: range(x) if type(x) != range else x)
print(df.groupby(['col_2']).groups)```
````

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your  code gives an error when printing the groups:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'range'